# make scrapy request depending on outcome of prior request?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping data where for each user, I don't know if there will be data for the entire time period. Therefore I would like to first call the API on a large chunk of time and then if there are results, call the API for smaller increments of time within that large chunk. I originally tried just grabbing data for the large chunk, but the API seems to have some documented max records to show and sometimes only shows part of a record, leading to json formatting problems and incomplete data. What's the smart way to write a spider that generates new Request objects based on length of response object from prior Request objects? I haven't tried anything because all I can think of is to create Requests within the parse method of a spider, but this seems wrong. Thanks for any suggestions/pointers to what I've missed in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally normal to create Requests within the `parse` method (or any other callback method, `parse` is just the default).

Scrapy is designed so that any callback can return a list of data items or Requests, and Scrapy will process the output handling each thing differently (sending items to pipeline to be stored or whatever, or scheduling new requests -- with possibly different configured callbacks).

This is better explained in the overview page soon to be released for the next Scrapy version, you can sneak-peek here: http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/master/intro/overview.html

Note that the example code is using features not yet released (yielding dicts, `response.urljoin` method), but the explanations are valid.